# How to install eAccelerator for XAMPP on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion

Tags: php, xampp, osx-lion, eaccelerator

I had some problems installing eAccelerator on XAMPP installation of Mac OS X Lion.

Firstly, I had this problem:

```
 Mohd-Yusufs-MacBook-Pro:APC-3.1.9 mohdyusuf$ $PHP_PREFIX/bin/phpize
    grep: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/main/php.h: No such file or directory
    grep: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend/zend_modules.h: No such file or directory
    grep: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/include/php/php-5.3.1/php/Zend/zend_extensions.h: No such file or directory
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:        
    Zend Module Api No:     
    Zend Extension Api No:
```

So I solved it by installing "Developer package" from XAMPP download page.

Then, I had problems with compiled version of eAccelerator:

```
 PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/eaccelerator.so' - dlopen(/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/eaccelerator.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/php-5.3.1/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/eaccelerator.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Under eAccelerator source dir:

> make clean
>
> ./configure CFLAGS='-arch i386' APXSLDFLAGS='-arch i386' --enable-eaccelerator=shared --with-php-config=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin/php-config
>
> make
>
> sudo make install

Ps: dont forget to enable eaccelerator.so extention under /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini