# Installing Memcache on OS X - XAMPP Developer package?

Tags: macos, memcached, xampp

Im running Mac OSX 10.6 and trying to get memcache installed locally.

I have hit the exact issue detailed here

[How to install eAccelerator for XAMPP on Mac OS X 10.7 Lion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8330536/how-to-install-eaccelerator-for-xampp-on-mac-os-x-10-7-lion)

Which leads me to believe that the issue I am facing is due to me having never installed said "XAMPP Developer Package".

I can't seem to find anything anywhere that allows me to install the XAMPP developer package. Cant even find much that references what it even is or what it does. Is anyone able to elaborate on this?

Comment: *Tumbleweeds* 3 Years on and still no answer.